# Avoid eclipse from formatting preprocessor directives

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I use Blackberry java plug-in for eclipse to write code. I have preprocessor statements in my code in the following way

```
     //#ifdef OS50
         //run this
     //#else
          //run this
     //#endif
```

Every time I do "Format" (CTRL+SHIFT+F) on this bit of code, eclipse adds a space between '//' and '#'. So if I format the above code it ends up like this

```
     // #ifdef OS50
         //run this
     // #else
          //run this
     // #endif
```

This then tells eclipse that I have comments rather than preprocessor directives. Hence I cant compile. Is there any way I could avoid eclipse doing this to my code when I format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify your formatter's settings not to format line comments so that no white spaces will be added:

1. In Eclipse go to *Window -> Preferences*
2. browse on the right pane to *Java -> Code Style -> Formatter*
3. click *Edit...*
4. Go to the Comments tab and uncheck *Enable line comment formatting*

Hope this helps!

BTW, if you don't want it to apply to everything you do in Eclipse, you can set it only for this project by clicking the *Configure Project Specific Settings* instead of the edit button in step 3.

Comment: your welcome! I've edited the answer if you want this to be project specific  :)

Comment: @rfsk2010 and Tamar, Thanks for this question and answer :p.